# Retorno completo do tipo Date

Tags: java, datetime, data

Como faço para obter esse retorno?

**2014-08-05 18:29:47.757**

Utilizando o `Date`.

```
Date data = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
```

Utilizando isso meu retorno é apenas **2015-02-03** e não retorna as horas.

**OBS.:** preciso obter o valor assim para passar como `timeStamp` para o banco.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você precisa pedir a informação toda explicitamente com [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html) e formatá-la com [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.S").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/KRXca4). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/FormatCalendar). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/FormatCalendar.java).

Na edição da pergunta (que depois foi removida) diz que precisa do *timestamp*, aí tem outra solução mais simples pegando direto o *timestamp*:

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/xeKQ81). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/getMiliseconds). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/GetMiliseconds.java).

[Dcoumentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()).

Note que estamos falando de formatação da apresentação da data e hora. Internamente um tipo `date` armazena toda a informação sempre. Se vai usar um dado deste tipo, ele sempre terá toda precisão. O fato de você não ver é um problema de apresentação apenas.

Comment: eu tinha olhado isso, porém resta uma dúvida isso gera uma String eu consigo converter em Date?

Comment: É possível, claro, mas precisa ver o que você quer fazer com ela, porque pode não ser preciso. Ter um retorno com o formato que você deseja é diferente de ter a data como você quer. A representação interna do tipo `Date` não interessa para você quando está usando no seu programa e sim como usá-la da maneira que precisa. No código exemplo que você colocou você diz que tem um retorno, mas este código não retorna nada visível. A apresentação do valor é diferente do valor. Mas editei para responder o que você perguntou na edição. Acho que é o que realmente você quer. Ou a pergunta está toda errada

Comment: Acredito que eu possa ter confundido vocês ao editar minha pergunta. O que está acontecendo é eu preciso gravar nesse padrão no banco **2014-08-05 18:29:47.757**.

Comment: Obrigado pelo link @bigown.

Comment: Se você quer gravar no banco de dados em um formato específico, você fará isto em um tipo de texto, talvez um `varchar`, então você gravará uma *string* nele. O primeiro exemplo que eu coloquei revolverá para você. Se você quer gravar data, não pode especificar formato, mesmo no banco de dados a representação interna é problema do tipo de dado. Formato só faz sentido em apresentação, em em armazenamento. A não ser que você queria armazenar a apresentação. Mas se quer a data corrente no banco de dados mande ele fazer isto e não o Java.

Comment: Entendi, acredito que minha coluna ser um @dateTime resolva se eu passar o currentTimeMillis, como na documentação ele fala que retorna a data atual em millisegundos.

Comment: É uma possibilidade. Depende do que você quer. Mas se o seu problema é pegar a data atual para por no banco de dados, o mais correto é deixar o banco de dados colocar tal informação independente do Java. Se não sabe como fazer isto abra uma pergunta para o banco de dados que você usa. Novamente, não sei sua situação específica, então posso estar enganado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20802/discussion-between-wellington-avelino-and-bigown).

Comment: Finalmente entendi, fiz como você falou e deu certo!
debuguei e vi o que não estava explicito no retorno, mesmo sem ir para o **sysout** ele atribui o valor corretamente a variavel. Obrigado @bigown

Comment: Não acho que o comentário valha uma resposta em separado, porém gostaria de apontar que o Java 8 introduziu novas  classes como [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) e [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). A ideia é que as pessoas aos poucos comecem a utilizar essas novas APIs.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
String dataFormatada = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").format(new Date());
```

Para converter de volta para `Date`:

```
Date data = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse(dataFormatada);
```

Comment: Tentei utilizar dessa forma, estou utilizando uma propriedade InicioOcorrencia no meu BackBean do tipo Date, e seto **ocorrencia.setInicioOcorrencia(dataformatada)** quando o retorno acontece ele fala que não consegue trabalhar com String.

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino Qual o tipo de parâmetro que esse método aceita?

Comment: Tipo Date segue o erro **The method setInicioOcorrencia(Date) in the type Ocorrencia is not applicable for the arguments (String)**

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino Então você tem que passar o objeto `Date` mesmo. O método que tem que cuidar de formatar a saída da forma que ele precisar.

Comment: Uma dúvida eu devo utilizar **java.sql.Date** ou **java.util.Date** no meu BackingBean?
Sei que essas dúvidas são coisas simples, mas estou num momento critico, sou estágiario e estou sozinho na equipe :(

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino Dá uma olhada nessa resposta do SO em inglês: [java.util.Date vs java.sql.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2306051/4443230)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda @André Ribeiro,me ajudou bastante entendi como funciona o Date, agora é só evoução!